Dynamically create n tasks in airflow from params
I want to dynamically create n taks, n should be defined by params, so i can define it when running the dag in the UI:
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["forest_hpo"],
    params={"n": 3}
)
def dynamic_test():

    @task()
    def model_training_task(i):
        print(i)

    for i in range(n): # <-- n should come from the params
        model_training_task(i)

dynamic_test()

Access "params" in body of dag is a similar question. However, the provied solution only shows how to use the params in a task, but not on DAG level...

Using Dynamic Task Mapping:
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["forest_hpo"],
    params={"n": 3}
)
def dynamic_test():

    @task()
    def get_list_from_params(params:dict):
        return list(range(params["n"]))

    @task()
    def model_training_task(i):
        print(i)

    model_training_task.expand(i=get_list_from_params())

dynamic_test()

A task that returns a list to iterate on is needed as far as I know.
Result:

See how model_training_task was scheduled 3 times. You can inspect the log in Mapped Tasks.

Thanks, very interesting solution! I was not aware of  mapped tasks. (It still feels odd to spin up an entire task instance just to get a parameter, but seems to be the only way to do it).
